# Does apple apply the app icon gloss effect and corner rounding on every icon?

Tags: iphone, icons

The iTunes Connect Developer Guide says that the developer must provide a whole bunch of different icon sizes. But I only know from the "normal" app icons (57x57, 114x114) that the device applies the gloss effect and corner rounding automatically.

But how about those other icons? How about the 512x512 iTunesArtwork.png icon? Are the effects applied automatically? Must this icon be shipped inside the bundle of the app? Is there any way to see it "live" how it finally looks, when those effects are applied?

I slightly remember that there was a tool from apple that applied those effects to an icon, so you could see them. Does anyone know more details about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually should supply 6 icons now.  One for the iPhone4, iPad, normal iphones/ipod touch, and 2 smaller icons for spotlight search (one is double resolution).

I wrote a pretty cool photoshop script to take you 512px icon and convert it using photoshop into 6 smaller sizes all named correctly.

http://github.com/sponno/iPhone-Photoshop-JSX-Icon-Exporter

You will also see in the header of the file, now to update your info.plist to include all these icons.

Comment: Excellent, Sir! Not only that your script is incredibly useful, but you also deserve a prize for mentioning this in the header of your script: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html  <<< This top secret document contains the relevant information we all were looking for our whole lifes so far. It should be statically attached to the home page of http://developer.apple.com. Really top secret, valuable stuff. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. That link was a super duper P.I.T.A to find. So like a great coder, I thought, I would put it in my script tool. Glad this has helped someone : )

Answer (score 28):

The glow and rounded corners are applied automatically. You can control the glow, by adding a key to your Info.plist file: `UIPrerenderedIcon` set to YES will indicate that your icon is "prerendered" and you don't want the glow.

The AppStore will honor that setting for the 512x512 icon as well.

Comment: So I add this 512x512 icon to my app bundle?

Comment: No. You upload the 512x512 icon to iTunes Connect when submitting the app. iTunes will honor the setting in the plist for that file as well.

Answer (score 1):

For more details on those six icons and their required sizes, here's two great resources:

- http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes
- http://blog.cocoia.com/2010/iphone-4-icon-psd-file/

Comment: The main problem is: Where to add them? Apple doesn't tell it. And I can't imagine this huge itunesartwork icon goes into the bundle. That would be really stupid.

Comment: From what I gather, they have to be plist'd and then probably the location is not too important: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831311/application-icon-for-iphone-3g-3gs-and-iphone-4/3831372#3831372

Answer (score 1):

Note that even though the app store honors the UIPrerenderedIcon setting for the icons supplied with your app bundle, the 512x512 icon submitted within iTunesConnect in the app management must not have rounded corners or gloss. If you click the ? next to the icon in iTunesConnect you get this message:

"A large version of your app icon that will be used on the App Store. It must be at least 72 DPI and a minimum of 512 by 512 pixels (it cannot be scaled up). It must be flat artwork without rounded corners."

Why they make it such a p.i.t.a. and make you provide a square icon for this is beyond me. My app icon is rounded with a decorative frame, this square version will look like a**.