# Application icon for iPhone 3g, 3gs and iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

I am planning an app for iphone 3g, 3gs and iphone 4. I have a 57*57 image for 3g and 3gs. When I checked documentation apple suggests us to use a 114*114 image for iphone 4. So how can I support both the images with the same build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the iPhone 4 icon `Icon@2x.png`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

Answer (score 7):

Use the CFBundleIconFiles property in your Info.plist and supply two icons, you name the high-resolution one with an "@2x" suffix so the iOS knows it's the high-resolution icon to use on iPhone 4. You can also specify iPad icons (for apps that run on iPhone and iPad) using the same property. This is documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html

Comment: My understanding is that the "@2x" suffix _only_ works if you do not specify the icon extension in your plist, i.e. ".png".

Comment: You can specify the suffix if you want, but if you do then you need to specify each icon explicitly. From the apple docs (linked in my answer): "When specifying icon files using the CFBundleIconFiles key, it is best to omit the filename extensions of your image files. If you include a filename extension, you must explicitly add all of your image files (including any high-resolution variants) to the array. When you omit the filename extension, the system automatically detects high-resolution variants of your file using the base filename you provide."

Answer (score 1):

You have to list all your icons in your Application's plist, and name the ones for iPhone 4 "Name@2x.ext" (add '@2x' to your file's name).

Answer (score 1):

If you place the original icon and an icon with the same name but add @2x to the end of the name in your resources folder the correct one will be used automaticly.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of [different possible icon sizes for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) is getting pretty long now. But all you need to do is to list all of the files in your app's [Info.plist in the `CFBundleIconFiles` key](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW10), and the OS will do the work of picking the correct size.